# What's the difference between the below two ways to place <div>?

Tags: html

could anyone tell me what's the difference between the below two ways to place?

I can see the visual differences but don't understand why.

```html
<div class="column">
  <img src="//placekitten.com/100/100" alt="Forest" style="width:100%">
  <img src="//placekitten.com/100/101" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%">
</div>
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <img src="//placekitten.com/100/100" alt="Forest" style="width:100%">
</div>
<div class="column">
  <img src="//placekitten.com/100/101" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%">
</div>
```

Comment: "I can see the visual differences" — I can't.

Comment: One of them has **one** `div` with two images in it, the other has **two** `div`s with one image each. If there's any padding or margin on the div elements, you'll see a difference.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the definition of the `column` class. Normally `div` elements are block elements, but that behavior can be overridden with the CSS `display` attribute. Columns are in a row, so in that case the `div` elements with the `column` CSS class would be redefined to be inline elements or inline block elements.

The first markup is one column with two full-width images in the column which would align vertically since the width is 100%.

The second markup is two elements intended as columns with an image in each. They could either be vertical or horizontal depending on how the `column` class is defined.

When using columns normally you would wrap both columns in some kind of "row" class.

You might want to look into a CSS framework such as [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/columns/) which makes it easier for you.